# Reference Classes, tab completion and forced method definition

Tags: r, r-s4, reference-class

I am currently writing a package using reference classes. I have come across
an issue which from reading various sources:

[Method initialisation in R reference classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331518/method-initialisation-in-r-reference-classes)

[Can't reliably use RefClass methods in Snowfall](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-June/061260.html)

I gather is caused because reference methods are not all copied to every object
in the class rather they are copied when first accessed.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-June/061261.html

As an example define:

```
test <- setRefClass("TEST",
                fields = list( a = "numeric"),
                methods = list(
                   addone = function(){
                                        a <<- a+1
                                      },
                   initialize = function(){
                                            a <<- 1
                                          }
                              )
               )

example <- test$new()
```

So example is a new object of class `TEST`. Typing `example$` and tabbing in the 
console gives

```
> example$
# example$.->a         example$.refClassDef example$.self        
# example$a            example$initialize
```

so the method `addone` is not presented as an option. It is available to 
call however:

```
example$addone()
```

Now tabbing again reveals

```
# > 
# > example
# Reference class object of class "TEST"
# Field "a":
# [1] 2
# > example$
# example$.->a         example$.refClassDef example$.self        
# example$a            example$addone       example$field        
# example$initialize   example$show
```

so now `addone` and `field` and `show` are presented as options.

Martin Morgan advises to force definition of the methods in one of the above links. This
works well

```
test <- setRefClass("TEST",
                fields = list( a = "numeric"),
                methods = list(
                   addone = function(){
                                        a <<- a+1
                                      },
                   initialize = function(){
                                            a <<- 1
                                            .self$addone #force definition
                                          }
                              )
               )

example <- test$new()
```

so now tabbing gives:

```
# > example$
# example$.->a         example$.refClassDef example$.self        
# example$a            example$addone       example$initialize
```

Some of my classes have over 30 methods so I would like to do this as succintly as possible.
I have defined:

```
test <- setRefClass("TEST",
                fields = list( a = "numeric"),
                methods = list(
                   addone = function(){
                                        a <<- a+1
                                      },
                   initialize = function(){
                      a <<- 1
                      eval(parse(text=paste0('.self$',ls(test$def@refMethods))))
                                          }
                              )
               )

example <- test$new()
```

tabbing now gives:

```
# > example$
# example$.->a         example$.refClassDef example$.self        
# example$a            example$addone       example$callSuper    
# example$copy         example$export       example$field        
# example$getClass     example$getRefClass  example$import       
# example$initFields   example$initialize   example$show         
# example$trace        example$untrace
```

Whilst this works it feels a bit clumsy. Also `test$def@refMethods` is used rather then `getRefClass("TEST")$def@refMethods` so that 
feels a bit wrong. Has anyone dealt with this issue before.

Is there a better way to approach a solution? Thanks for any advice and apologies if the question is overly drawn out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder what your objective is? Function names showing up with tab completion? Then it's worth a post to the R-devel mailing list with a feature request. The original scenario is more elegantly handled with `usingMethods` as documented on `?setRefClass`. A continued hack might be

```
initialize = function(...) {
    methods <- getRefClass(class(.self))$methods()
    eval(parse(text=paste0(".self$", methods)))
    callSuper(...)
}
```

Tab completions can be customized via `.DollarNames` in the `utils` package, so

```
.DollarNames.TEST <- function(x, pattern)
    grep(pattern, getRefClass(class(x))$methods(), value=TRUE)
```

Maybe an S3 method could be written at the base of your class hierarchy for this?

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful and more elegant than my solution. Also I didnt know it was termed tab completion. Knowing this term enabled me to find the relevant package in utils. Tab completion with reference classes was my objective and I will edit the question title to better reflect this.

Comment: This seems very promising. Would it be a bad idea to add `.DollarNames.envRefClass <- function(x, pattern)     grep(pattern, getRefClass(class(x))$methods(), value=TRUE)` to my package?

Comment: Yes, it would be a bad idea -- you'd change behavior for all reference classes, not just your own. Perhaps some like it's current behavior, perhaps `methods` will at some future date implement a super-duper `.DollarNames.envRefClass` and your long-forgotten method will then override this. The right thing to do is to bring this up on R-devel as a feature request, especially now that you have at least a working prototype to illustrate the behavior you think appropriate.

Comment: Martin Morgan thank you for your time and expertise. I will post a feature request to R-devel.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but it is still the top entry when searching for refClass tab completion on google, so I'll just add an update:

Instead of using grep in the .DollarNames function as suggested by Martin, use findMatches from the utils package as it plays better with the different Rgui's around (grep will delete your partially typed name upon hitting tab)

```
.DollarNames.TEST <- function(x, pattern){
    utils:::findMatches(pattern, getRefClass(class(x))$methods())
}
```

This is also how tab completion is handled internally for lists and data.frames

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Morgan noted that this was termed tab completion. The package `rcompletion` and later `rcompgen` were tasked with achieving this. They have been now moved to `utils`.

[rcompletion update](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-R-pkgs-rcompletion-update-td815363.html)

I looked thru the code for `completion.R` and from what I could determine `utils:::.DollarNames.environment` was handling tab completion for reference classes.

[completion.R](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/utils/R/completion.R)

Redefining the function seemed to achieve tab completion:

```
assignInNamespace( x = ".DollarNames.environment",
                     function(x, pattern = "") {
    y <- NULL
    if(isS4(x) && !is.null(x[['.refClassDef']])){
      if(.hasSlot(x$.refClassDef,'refMethods')){
        y<-x$.refClassDef@refMethods
        y<-ls(y, all.names = TRUE, pattern = pattern)
      }
    }
    x<-ls(x, all.names = TRUE, pattern = pattern)
    unique(c(x,y))
                                               }
,ns = "utils")
```

Some things to note:

- I would only use this for my own use. Currently I am debugging and documenting a package. I had some longish method names and couldnt remember exactly what they were so tab completion will help greatly.
- Usage of `assignInNamespace` in a package is frowned upon (if not banned) see `?assignInNamespace`.
- Forced definition of methods is more advisable.

Comment: Actually, `.DollarNames` is an S3 generic so you can write S3 methods on it; I illustrated this in my answer.